# custom delegate cannot be called from success block of AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, block, afnetworking

I have created a custom delegate that is working well. But when I try to call the delegate from inside the success block of an AFNetworking call, the delegate call is never made. Any idea why this is?

```
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
    NSLog(@"Check if delegate exists %@", self.delegate);// returns null

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(myMethod)]) {
            NSLog(@"Selector myMethod found and called");
            [self.delegate myMethod];
        }
    });


}
```

Notice that the NSLog statement returns null for `self.delegate`. Also I try the call with and without `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`. Again, If I make the call outside of the success block it works: so the problem has nothing to do with how I created the delegate :). Thanks.

Comment: How is the delegate defined?  Is it possible that the delegate property is being released before the success call?

Comment: @RishiG my delegate is declared as `@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyDelegate> delegate;` because that's how I see it done on absolutely every tutorial I ever see. But based on your comment, I change it to `strong` and behold it works. Are there any dangers to making a delegate declaration `strong`?

Comment: I am not an expert, but I would be more concerned with why the delegate object is being released when you still need it.  Is this object the only one that needs to retain it?  Seems like a deeper architectural bug.

Answer (score 1):

`....self.delegate);// returns null`

Well, the delegate is not set.

---

Anyway, mixing block callbacks and delegations seems to be very odd. just let the delegator add the block that is executed.
Furthermore AFNetworking does call it's block on the main queue/thread, you don't have to dispatch that code.